# Multiple Independent View Models Interacting (Knockout)

Tags: asp.net, mvvm, knockout.js, typescript

I have a view model in a ASP.Net application set up right now to handle some data binding and it interacts with a Razor template on my main view that is shared across several pages. I have a select box in the Razor template that has a data binding on my current view model, but I would have to duplicate this code across several view models to gain the same functionality and I want to just have this part of my view model be abstracted just like my template is an abstraction of the part of the view it is on. Ideally what I want is something like the following (psuedo-code):

```
class ViewModel1{
       function doSomeAjaxStuff(option from select){

       }

      function doSomethingOnSelectorChange(option from select){
           call doSomeAjaxStuff(option from select);

      }
}

class SelectorViewModel{
       function getSelectorValuesFromAjax(){
          //this function will populate the selectors values from an ajax call
       }

       function sendMessageThatSelectorHasChanged(){
           //this will send to the first viewmodel that the selector value has changed

       }
}
```

I am a bit new to the MVVM architecture and I'm not exactly sure how to do this with knockout. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Yeah I'm using TypeScript, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking to implement something like a *reusable control* using Knockout. One approach we're currently taking is using custom binding handlers in conjunction with template scripts. For example, given some templates:

```
<script type="text/html" id="selector-template">
    <!-- ko if: isLoading -->
    Loading data...
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: isLoading -->
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="
            css: { selected: $parent.selectedItem == $data }, 
            template: $parent.itemTemplate, 
            click: selectItem">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

...and a binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selector = {
    init: function(element, valuesAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var bindingValues = valuesAccessor();

        var templateElem = document.createElement('div');
        templateElem.setAttribute('data-bind', 'template: "selector-template"');
        element.appendChild(templateElem);

        var viewModelForControl = new SelectorViewModel(bindingValues);
        var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModelForControl);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

...you could instantiate the custom control like this:

```
<div data-bind="selector: { 
    itemsUrl: urlForItems, 
    selected: doSomethingOnSelectorChange,
    itemTemplate: 'product-list-item-template'
}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="product-list-item-template">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }" />
    <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
</script>
```

Comment: this is a great answer, we ended up changing our architecture a bit so the question wasn't entirely the same by the end of the day but thank you for the help!